# Is config.json file encrypted?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I have a private key that I am using to hash data, that key is also on the server. I was wondering if its safe to store this value in the config.json file in an Appcelerator Alloy application? When decompiling the ipa/apk is that something anyone could see?

If not is there a better location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alloy will compile the `config.json` file into `CFG.js` file which like all other JS files in a Titanium app will be encrypted. By default the key is stored in a compiled Obj-C class in the app.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.